# How do we determine the class of the IP address?

Tags: networking, ip, system-administration

I am currently trying to understand the IP address's class. I came across two ways to determine the class of IP address:

1) Format (eg. N.H.H.H = class A, N.N.H.H = class B)

2) bits in the beginning of the IP address ( eg. 0xxx.xxxx.xxxx = class A)

Is the identification of class of IP determined by 1 && 2 (by this I mean satisfy rule 1 and 2) rule or 1 || 2( by this I mean satisfy rule 1 or 2)?

```
For 128.138.243.100/26

Address:   128.138.243.100       10000000.10001010.11110011.01 100100
Netmask:   255.255.255.192 = 26  11111111.11111111.11111111.11 000000
Wildcard:  0.0.0.63              00000000.00000000.00000000.00 111111
=>
Network:   128.138.243.64/26     **10**000000.10001010.11110011.01 000000 (Class B)
Broadcast: 128.138.243.127       10000000.10001010.11110011.01 111111
HostMin:   128.138.243.65        10000000.10001010.11110011.01 000001
HostMax:   128.138.243.126       10000000.10001010.11110011.01 111110  
Hosts/Net: 62
```

How could 128.138.243.100/26 be class B if we flow rule 1. Since rule 1 says class B should be N.N.H.H but in the above example clearly the N part of the IP address is beyond N.N.N.(here it even encroaches two bit of the H ).

Comment: It really says 'this is a 62 host subnet of what looks like, historically, a class B network, based on its identifier'. Note how those first two bits are highlighted with asterisks

Comment: IP addresses haven't had classes for twenty years. They have netmasks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Understand that RFCs have obsoleted classes, so there really aren't any classes anymore, but they are still referred to historically.

The class of an IP address is determined by the starting bits of the address:

- Starts with `0`, it is a Class A
- Starts with `10`, it is a Class B
- Starts with `110`, it is a class C
- Starts with `1110`, it is a class D
- Starts with `1111`, it is a Class E

In your example, the address is a Class B because of the starting bits, but it is in a *subnet* of the Class B *network*.

`128.138.243.100/26` is:

```
       |     NETWORK     |   SUBNET  | HOST |
Address 10000000.10001010.11110011.01 100100
Mask    11111111.11111111.11111111.11 000000
```

Comment: thank you ron for nice answer... so subnet is introduced here for class B (N.N.H.H) because the networkd part of bit (N.N) was not enough to maintain the huge demand of IP's needed, so we just used host part bit (H.H) as network part, to increase the number of network ? please let me know if my understanding here is correct :)

Comment: I think this question and answer will help you: http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/7106/how-do-you-calculate-the-prefix-network-subnet-and-host-numbers